# I'm getting 419 error after logout and login again

Tags: laravel-8, php-7.4

I get a 419 error after, I logout and i try to login again
I have the csrf token in my form, but it didn't change
it's like the view was in cache

AuthController.php

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    $request->session()->regenerateToken();
    header("Refresh:0");
    return redirect('/'); 
}
```

I'm reloading my login page and I always get the same csrf token, but when i clear my cache, I get a new token and i am able to login, what can i do?

Comment: ...`Auth::logout();` is enough for logout, why you need all of those things?

Comment: I saw it in official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#logging-out

Comment: wow it's new, until 7.x there was no need for other "lines of code"... try removing them and see if the error is still there

Comment: I checked and Im getting randomly 419 error in differents requests, when im still logged, its very strange I have @csrf in all my blade forms. I resolved it disabling csrf middleware but, but i dont undestand why is this happening